# please suggest me what is wrong?? it only shows element not found

Tags: python-2.7

```
def binsearch(a,c):

    first=0
    last=len(a)-1
    found=False

    while first<=last and not found:
        mid=(first+last)//2
        if(a[mid]==c):
            found=True           
        elif a[mid]<c:
             last=mid-1
        else:
            first=mid+1
    return found        
a=list()

n=raw_input("Enter how many elements:")

for i in range(int(n)):

    num=raw_input("Enter the elements:")
    a.append(int(num))


c=raw_input("Enter the element u wanna search:")

b=binsearch(a,c)

if b:

    print "Element",c,"found in position."

else:

    print "Element not found."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that `c` is a string.
Just add `c = int(c)` after the `c = raw_input("...")` line

Comment: Thanks a lot fr your help...it worked